# Where are moderators and admins from Ebook.SE?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

We have a poor rating on the number of questions.

It's sad that a lot of questions that should be on the Ebook.SE is spread everywhere else. (Superuser, Software recommendations etc.)

Users obviously take questions where the user base is active.

Where are the moderators and admins from Ebook.SE?

What if users with a 1000+ reputation on all SE sites should recommend migrating these questions?

Should I make a list of these questions for assessment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don’t have the power to take questions from other sites. If you see a question on another site that should be here—that is, it’s on-topic here and off-topic or a bad fit there—then you should raise a flag on that site to ask that it be migrated to this one.

Comment: Some questions might fit into multiple sides. By asking a question on one side might also appear on another side. If there is a problem with the allocation of reputations, I think that, if it has such an overlap, the reputations should be attributed to on all sides equally. This determination would be done using tags.

Comment: That's not how the network works. We actively *discourage* people from asking questions on multiple sites because it means the best answers are scattered around various places. It wouldn't make sense to include the question on multiple sites because you'd have problems of conflicting moderation, not to mention answers that only make sense from a certain perspective and would be confusing to others. The sites are distinct for good reasons.

Comment: Some questions can not be atomized. The overlap will always be. As someone on Meta.SE remarked: "Another group with a different point of view has its own answer to the question."
Why can not there be one administrative and moderator core? Egoism?
What brings reputation? Any unimportant person can answer.
For me the correctness of the answer is important and not how much the corresponding user has reputation points.
And google will show both questions, right?

Comment: None of that really addresses your proposal. In any case, what you are suggesting is not a change to Ebooks.se but a sweeping change to how every Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange site works, at both the software and philosophical levels. We have no power to make such a change, nor is such a proposal on-topic on this site. It belongs on [meta.se], but will not be well-received there (it’s a duplicate of lots of existing proposals).

Comment: I noticed it.
It's a little obscure. I will have to add another page - philosophy. :-D The thought stream is fragmented.